# MVC5 - Entity loaded in base controller conflicting with entity updates elsewhere

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a base controller that loads an EF6 entity in a protected Dictionary member. But somehow it stops other controllers from updating that entity. Below is the simplified code -

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {
    protected IDictionary<string, int> MyList;
    public BaseController() {
        MyList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var rc in db.MyTable.Where(r => r.IsActive).ToList())
                MyList.Add(rc.Name, rc.Id);
        ViewBag.MyListViewBag = MyList;
    }
}


public class MyController : BaseController {
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,...other properties")] MyTable mt) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(mt).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(mt);
    }
}
```

The error is "Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value" and it is thrown at `db.Entry(mt).State = EntityState.Modified;`

As you can see, BaseController loads the entity in a list first, that should severe any connections (at least I thought it would). Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mt` variable, which you take from action arguments, is not a part of EF tracked objects. So, you should take it from `db` and then update it's necessary properties:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,...other properties")] MyTable mt) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var temp = db.MyTable.Single(mt.Id);
        temp.Name = mt.Name;
        //copying of other properties...
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(mt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. Still strange that the existing code was working just fine until the entity was accessed in base controller.